# Redirect users to specific list when users come to access denied page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-denied

I have given full control by 'stop inheriting permission' on 1 list(**Tasks list**) to 1 user(**Demo user**). So user automatically gets limited access in sharepoint site(**www.demo.com**) when user open (**www.demo.com/Lists/Tasks**) user is able to open the site, but when user enter just site url (**www.demo.com**) user gets access denied page. Now i want to redirect user to Tasks list if user gets access denied page.
How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Normally, a user should not get access denied error on the parent object (root site in your case) as it has Limited Access permissions on it.

Comment: i am bit confuse regarding this. Let me explain the problem more clearly. Actually i have 1 custom page inside 'Site Pages' library and that is the site home page. i checked for 'Site Pages' library permissions and user have limited access to 'Site Pages' too. can u guide me how should i manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Give the user read permissions on the Site Pages Library. That will give the user Limited Access permissions on the root site. Moreover, because of read permissions on Site Pages Library, user will be able to see the content in your home page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u Nadeem Yousuf. Yes thats the solution i thought, but for that i have to break permission inheritance in 'Site Pages' too that is what i dont want and i have some custom web parts on the home page that shows data from many other lists and i dont want to show them to a Demo user. Any other idea?

Comment: Can u try breaking the permission of the item which represents your home page and give the user read permissions on that item. That will prevent Site Pages library from breaking inheritance.

Comment: Right. i already thought that. But the home page that i have set is page with custom webpart. Often i need to delete this page and add new page with same name programmatically. so i think it would not be a realible to break the permission of the home page and give the user read permission. Second reason is my another custom code is used to add new user so if i break the permission then the user added by my another code will not get permission to the page.

Comment: Well, you don't want to give user permission either on the list or the list item, then how can the user see the homepage without access?

Comment: yes thats the problem. so i want to redirect him anyway.